# Error in timer loop AVFoundtion

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am using the code below which is executes every second using a timer.

I am using it to update a label with the elapsed time in a music player app.

However I get an error occurring which gives a back trace with the following line:

> CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION
>
> stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT

All breakpoints are disabled.

why is this error occurring?

```
func updateTime() {
    // more code above
    
    let length = Int64((player.currentItem?.duration.value)!) / Int64((player.currentItem?.duration.timescale)!)

    // more code below
}
```

Comment: Interesting bug. Do you mind putting a dummy project that can reproduce this error on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be triggered by force unwrapping a `nil` optional. Also, there are helper functions for dealing with `CMTime` structs.

Try the following:

```
guard let duration = player.currentItem?.duration else {
    return
}
let length = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
```